# IntegerProperty cannot be converted to Observable

Tags: javafx

```
    Callback<IntegerProperty, Observable[]> extractor = 
(IntegerProperty p) -> { return new Observable[]{p}; };
```

I gets error: IntegerProperty cannot be converted to Observable.

What wrong?

Comment: Did you import `javafx.beans.Observable` or `java.util.Observable`? An `IntegerProperty` is the former.

Comment: You're right. I was wrong in importing the library.
Thanks for the help :)